# Windows VM is not accessible with public ip address

Tags: windows, azure, nginx, azure-virtual-network

I have azure windows server 2016 VM, I have installed nginx server to run php website. It is running with private IP address and localhost but not working with public ip address.

I have enabled port 80 in inbound port rules
[image: Inbound port rules]

My nginx configuration is :

```
server {
    listen       <my public IP>:80;
    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  C:/nginx-1.14.0/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: unable to telnet public address 80

Comment: Is port 80 in listening state using command `netstat -a`on the VM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can change the nginx configuration file like this:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.org www.example.org(not ip address);
    ...
    }
```

Then you can check if the port 80 is listening using command `netstat -a` on the VM. also, see if the port 80 is open in the firewall configuration on the VM side.

After the above steps, verify the network connection is working using `telnet publicipaddress 80` on the client.

If the result of telnet is normal, you can try to run php website with public IP address again.

For more references, refer to [How nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html).